# The trivility of Besov space for large parameter

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

For all $s>0$, $1\le p<+\infty$ and $u\in L^p(\mathrm{d}x)$, we define
$$D_{s,p}(u)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{r^{sp+n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{B(x,r)}|u(y)-u(x)|^p\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$
and
$$W^{s,p}(\mathrm{d}x)=\left\{u\in L^p(\mathrm{d}x):\lVert u\rVert_p+[D_{s,p}(u)]^{1/p}<+\infty\right\}$$
When $s>1$, $W^{s,p}(\mathrm{d}x)=\{0\}$.

Can someone give the reason for the trivility of $W^{s,p}(\mathrm{d}x)$ for $s>1$?

Comment: Let $u$ be continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x$. Then $u(y) = u(x) + Du(x) \cdot (y-x) + o(|y-x|)$. So $\int_{B(x,r)} |u(y) - u(x)|\mathrm{d}y$ as $r\to 0$ behaves like $C r^{n+p}$. So $D_{s,p}(u) = \infty$ for $s > 1$.

Comment: But we do not have the regularity of $u$.

Comment: No you do not. But you _can_ modify the above proof to show that $D_{s,p} < +\infty$ for $s > 1$ implies that $u$ is a.e. constant for $L^p$ functions.

Comment: If $u$ has some regularity near some points, then we can use the above proof. But for general $L^p$ functions such as $\mathbf{1}_{B_(0,1)}$, how can we use the above idea? The denseness of smooth functions of something? And it is the point I am not clear.

Comment: Try to see if you can estimate the $D_{s,p}$ of a _mollified_ version of $u$ by $D_{s,p}(u)$. It may be convenient to choose a non-negative mollifier. It may also help to use Minkowski's inequality.